# 100% of content, not of browser height using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a min-height 100% div that contains all the content of my website:

```
#SiteWrap { min-height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

The above div contains everything - the header, content and footer.

What I need to do is overlay an absolute positioned div on top (with a semi-transparent .png background) which basically sits above the entire site, effectively 'fading it out' slightly.

I can't seem to get the absolute div to fit to 100% of the site content. It just spans 100% of the browser height. When you scroll down the bottom section of content below the height of the browser are not spanned by the div.

I have tried this div which I put inside the SiteWrap div but it won't work:

```
#LoginPopup-Background { position: absolute; width: 100%; min-height: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 1100; background-color: #F39C11; }
```

(The background colour is for testing purposes).

Any ideas?

Comment: Set the popup height using Javascript (`document.getElementById('#LoginPopup-Background').style.height = document.body.offsetHeight + 'px'`), or use `position: fixed` instead of `absolute`, which will have the side effect that the login box will not scroll with the body.

Comment: Ahh that works perfectly! No side effect, I don't want the login box to scroll with the body. Thanks Blaise!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `position: fixed` instead of `position: absolute`. The login will still not be 100% size of the document but it will always cover the content even when you scroll.

Also for the IE you should always set `top: 0; left: 0` to prevent some strange layout errors.